# Iterating columns in R and converting it to a date time

Tags: r, datetime, iteration, multiple-columns

I have the following data frame in R:

```
head(sample_frame)
  average                   datetime    count
1   14.60   2011-05-30T20:38:37.000Z        1
2   13.79   2013-07-25T22:54:12.000Z        1
3   17.60   2009-09-16T18:34:46.000Z        1
4   22.53   2008-08-03T18:42:35.000Z        1
5   19.30   2009-02-08T21:12:22.000Z        1
6   18.95   2009-02-04T20:00:55.000Z        1
```

The datetime column is as of now factor and I want to convert it to a date/time class.

The issue is I wouldn't know in advance the column name so I would have to match the pattern of date time and try to convert it.

Following is the code that I have written:

```
  for(i in colnames(sample_frame))
   {
       if(regexpr("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z",sample_frame[1,i]) == 1)
       {
            sample_frame$i <- strptime(as.character(sample_frame$i),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ") 
       }
}
```

which doesn't work, the `regexpr` works but inside the code, it doesn't,
the following command works though,

```
sample_frame$datetime <- strptime(as.character(sample_frame$datetime),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @LukeA's answer, you could also use `lapply` instead of the `for` loop:

```
sample_frame[] <- lapply(sample_frame, function(x){
  if(grepl("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z", x[1])) {
    x <- as.POSIXct(as.character(x),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "")
    return(x)
  } else x })

sample_frame
#  average            datetime count
#1   14.60 2011-05-30 20:38:37     1
#2   13.79 2013-07-25 22:54:12     1
#3   17.60 2009-09-16 18:34:46     1
#4   22.53 2008-08-03 18:42:35     1
#5   19.30 2009-02-08 21:12:22     1
#6   18.95 2009-02-04 20:00:55     1
```

Answer (score 2):

To correct your `for` loop:

```
sample_frame <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="
average datetime count
1 14.60 2011-05-30T20:38:37.000Z 1
2 13.79 2013-07-25T22:54:12.000Z 1
3 17.60 2009-09-16T18:34:46.000Z 1
4 22.53 2008-08-03T18:42:35.000Z 1
5 19.30 2009-02-08T21:12:22.000Z 1
6 18.95 2009-02-04T20:00:55.000Z 1")

for(i in colnames(sample_frame)) { 
  if(grepl("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z",sample_frame[1, i])) {
    sample_frame[, i] <- as.POSIXct(as.character(sample_frame[, i]),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "") 
  }
}
sample_frame$datetime
# [1] "2011-05-30 20:38:37 CEST" "2013-07-25 22:54:12 CEST" "2009-09-16 18:34:46 CEST"
# [4] "2008-08-03 18:42:35 CEST" "2009-02-08 21:12:22 CET"  "2009-02-04 20:00:55 CET"
```

Comment: 1 question that i have is while converting, why is the format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" and not "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"

Comment: Because there`s a `.000` between `%S` and `Z`, so the pattern doesn't match and the function returns `NA`.